# I need this specific colour which i have a hex number, is it possible to add this in in this part of the code?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I need to be able to use hex for my colours because i want to use a specific green shade but i cant as i only have the option between default green. As you can see on Line 5.

I tried adding the hex which didnt work.

```
1. public ListTabPage()
2.       {
3.           InitializeComponent();
4.
5.          Color[] colorList = new Color[] { Color.Green, Color.Green, 
6. Color.Red, Color.Purple, Color.Black };
7.            this.CurrentPageChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
8.                var i = this.Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);
9.                App.UserPreferences.SetColor(colorList[i]);
10.
11.            };
12.        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [Color.FromHex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.color.fromhex?view=xamarin-forms)

```
Color.FromHex("002244AA");
```

more info about [Colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/colors) in Xamarin.Forms